# WebView open apps/default browser

Tags: android, html, ios, react-native

I am quite new to `React-native`. The href tag in HTML opens the website within the app. I wish to have it open the link in the default browser of the mobile phone/device. Oh and I use snack.expo.

- In APP a website is being loaded. Within my website I use `<a href>` 'http://maps.google.com/?q=...' I wish to have the default browser of a mobile phone to open this link in its default browser, same goes for other `href` links.
- Of course only links with target="_blank" should be opened in the default browser.
- It would be even more awesome if app's can be opened.

I have searched google a lot, but without success.

Anyone who knows how to do this? Or is it simply not available, yet?

---

Within my `HTML` code I've tried this:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q={address}" target="_blank">{address}</a>
```

Part of react native code:

```
  return (
  <WebView
    source={{ uri: '{website}' }}
  />
);
```

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible in `react native`. You can do it as follows:

```
import {Linking} from "react-native"  

       <WebView

   source={{uri:"https://mashupguide.net/1.0/html/ch02s05.xhtml"}}
  onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={request => {
    let url = request.url;
    if (url.includes("http://maps.google.com/")) {
      Linking.openURL(url);

      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }}
   />
```

This will prevent the `WebView` from browsing to the next page and instead open the phone's default browser.

reference: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#onshouldstartloadwithrequest

working example: https://snack.expo.io/@ammarahmed/sadistic-almond

Comment: Hi Ammar, I've added it to my code, but it does not open the default browser. The website is being opened within the app. Do you know any other possible solution?

Comment: It is working here. are you sure that the url you are trying to open from `href` opens as `target="_blank"`? try to remove `target==="_blank"` from the above code and also remove it from your `href` tag. also if you can share your html code here, it would be helpful to fix your issue. Thank You. Can you also mention the website you are opening the link from?

Comment: After '?q=' comes the address. Is it okay I do not have to provide that in the 'url.includes'? Ill edit the code now to test.

Comment: https://imgur.com/X2A7tcO an image to show you the result. As you can see the maps.google link opens within the app. I did both.Old code and new one like you asked me to try

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@ammarahmed/sadistic-almond .  I made a snack where I have implemented the above example code. test it with your own `uri`. as you can see, it opens up chrome or google maps if they are installed.

Comment: Hi Ammar, I see it works. But I can not make it working. Maybe its because in the source uri? And request.url doesnt correspondent with this request? Do you mind to have a chat with me and help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes definitely, you can contact me at ammarahmed6506@gmail.com